# App wide RTK query loading & fetching indicator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, rtk-query

In my **React** app, I am using **RTK** query to fetch data. I have **10+** API endpoints and a route for each one of the endpoints.

I want to show a **horizontal line** at the top of the page to indicate that the data fethcing is going on.

At the moment, I have done this.

```
const ArticlePage = () => {
  const { id} = useParams();
  const { data, isFetching, isLoading } = useFetchArticleByIdQuery(id);

  return (
    <Layout>
      {(isFetching || isLoading) && <LinearProgressIndicator />}
      <PageHead />
      {data && <ArticleContent article={data} />}
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

I have also tried this.

```
const ArticlePage = () => {
  const { id} = useParams();
  const { data, isFetching, isLoading } = useFetchArticleByIdQuery(id);

  return (
    <Layout>
      <LinearProgressIndicator shouldDisplay={(isFetching || isLoading)} />
      <PageHead />
      {data && <ArticleContent article={data} />}
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

It is cumbersome ot use the same thing on all the 10+ routes. So is there any way to show `<LinearProgressIndicator />` once for all the 10+ endpoints?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can write a selector for that:

```
  const isLoading = useAppSelector((state) => {
    return Object.values(state.api.queries).some((query) => {
      return query && query.status === QueryStatus.pending;
    });
  });
```

Comment: can it be shared via useQuery?

Comment: If you call useQuery for the same endpoint with the same argument, `isFetching` for that endpoint/argument combination will be shared across components.

Comment: can we separate isLoading and isFetching states in the similar manner? 
For instance, I need an overlay loader when table has no data but as we paginate I want to show a more subtle loading indicator within the table.

Comment: @OleksandrFomin no, as `isLoading` only exists on component level - answering the question if *this component* ever had data before. That's not known globally. `isFetching` is equal to `QueryStatus.pending`.